# Typescript support for generic Map functions

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to preserve typescript generic indexing when calling Map functions such as Map.set.
Suppose I have these types set up.

```
type DataKind = "string" | "number";

type MapsByKind = {
  string: Map<number, string>;
  number: Map<number, number>;
};

type ValueByKind = {
  string: string;
  number: number;
};
```

And I add a generic update type like

```
type UpdatePayload<T extends DataKind> = { readonly id: number; value: ValueByKind[T] };
```

Can I then define a function that will apply such an update to a provided map.
If I define it the following way it seems that once we reach the `.set` part the generic type is treated as a union, or something similar, no longer generic.

```
const applyUpdate = <T extends DataKind>(
  state: MapsByKind[T],
  payload: UpdatePayload<T>
) => {
  const {id,value}=payload; index by generic = ValueByKind[T]
  state //  MapsByKind[T]
  const setter = state.set // no longer generic but union
  const next = state.set(id,value) // I guess intersection
};
```

My guess is that typescript is not made for this, so may just use object typed with Record.

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBpAlgOwCZQLxQEQDOwATugOZ5QA%20%20aArgLYBGExeA3AFCeiRQCycMAQBCIVJhxQA3pyhQipNGQBcAoQB56zVgBoFJcgD4u87S2JrBYLYwv7zrE5wC%20XHuGgA1OABs6EGISWLiy8orkahHKplCOlnF2rFxu3LzQAKpgGAgQAApwIL4A9nAYGgAqUBAAHsAQmASwCMjoGEZS0lDEEGXFaL4gUCgYavHsUABufgFqPv6B4m0A2hUAulCpnADG-URQQmCDWTn1UpXVdQ0YTfCIwUYAFHIGuVZCokuYq2u6L2CFEplNQnXIFIqlcoVIycACUOA6YSguzQ%202kI100wWLmwAIhZQmLyIuReKP2BAgwHqxCkxPqADoKcBSXtgHFamzcHSIIzKY8MViAvDXOwgA)

Comment: The compiler doesn't see the relationship between `MapsByKind` and `ValueByKind`, but if you write `MapsByKind` as a mapped type over `ValueByKind` then it will work (as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)). See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mA8RBN).  Does that fully address your question? If so then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: okay I see, it's not really a map issue? yes that would be cool, I think its a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler is unable to see the correlation between `MapsByKind[T]` and `ValueByKind[T]` for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T`, even though it would be able to do so for any *specific* `T` like `"string"` or `"number"`.  The compiler is fairly limited in its ability to reason abstractly about higher-order type relationships.

And because of that the failure happens pretty much exactly as you described.  The compiler doesn't notice that `state` of type `MapsByKind[T]` and `value` of type `ValueByKind[T]` are related, so when you call `state.set(id, value)`, it widens `state` to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Map<number, string> | Map<number, number>`, meaning that `set` is also a union of methods, which in order to be safe will only accept an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of parameters (as [documented in the TS3.3 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)).  And that means `value` would need to be both a `string` *and* a `number` (which is impossible), but the compiler can only be sure that it's either a `string` *or* a `number`, so it fails.

This general inability of the compiler to see correlation between two expressions that derive from the same type is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  That issue is specifically about correlations between *union types*, which is what your generic code falls back to.

---

Luckily there is a way to address it, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The fix is generally to refactor so to use *generics* (which you've already done), but where the operations are in terms of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over a common basic type, and in terms of generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into such types.

Indeed, your code is very similar to the recommended way of doing it.  The `ValueByKind` type is exactly the common basic type.  And your function is properly generic in `T`, the keys of that type.  The only difference is that your `MapsByKind` type is written out manually instead of as a mapped type over `ValueByKind`.  If you make that change:

```
type MapsByKind = {
  [K in keyof ValueByKind]: Map<number, ValueByKind[K]>
};
/* type MapsByKind = {
    string: Map<number, string>;
    number: Map<number, number>;
} */
```

then suddenly everything works:

```
const applyUpdate = <T extends DataKind>(
  state: MapsByKind[T],
  payload: UpdatePayload<T>
) => {
  const { id, value } = payload;
  // const value: ValueByKind[T]

  const setter = state.set
  // const setter: (key: number, value: ValueByKind[T]) => MapsByKind[T]

  const next = state.set(id, value); // okay!
};
```

The type of `state.set` is now seen as the single, non-union, generic function type `(key: number, value: ValueByKind[T]) => MapsByKind[T]`, and since `value` is seen as `ValueByKind[T]`, the call succeeds!

---

Note how subtle the problem and its solution turned out to be.  The `MapsByKind` type is *equivalent* in both cases, and when you use IntelliSense to display the type, the display is *identical*.  But the internal representation of the type is crucially different: when `ValueByKind` is written as a mapped type over `MapsByKind`'s properties, the relationship between the two is visible to the compiler, whereas it is invisible when written independently.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-YSSX8VCCPsMmqYd-2PP8Ujaf9gOYEVHxlVsX1MKE6QmcU5kWP1EWRXhUREPYxDJA4jhOM4LiuG4RzuQUSheTtL2JAFELVY1wUhWkYQkOEsI2LZcN2TFqkDY8lSJP5SWqMUqU8FC1npdCmVZdl52YFi8EuYQBSebJRTQqkhxNeU1Jo55d3o5U-kQog1KNbVdWlIMjTJU0bM1bVPHRdc2Eo-8tKFOihVnYk2TEPY3wYyyvR5H0-XskZgxYUNNPDIUWTuU0plXCZxxzbMsiAA)